# 'Edit Collider' exits after every adjustment

Tags: unity, collider

When I click the *Edit Collider* button I can see the collider's region and the handles to adjust it.

After every adjustment (with the mouse) the collider outline disappears as *Edit Collider* finishes.  It's frustrating to use, having to reclick *Edit Collider* after every drag/click.

How do I stop *Edit Collider* mode from exiting after every change and only exit if I click the button, or press some commit key?

Answer (score 0):

When I had an issue like that, it drove me crazy.

It turned out that I had tried to edit the wrong collider.

So, double check that the collider you're clicking on is the collider that you're editing in the Inspector, and not a different instance of the same object, for example.